# How to stop functions recursion (in collectionView) by objective c in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, recursion, uicollectionview

**EDIT:** I admit my design has problem. As long as move my timer to a none-UI-related-function, the problem is solved.

First, I have multiple accounts. I have a collectionView to load one account's information.

Second, I have two functions. One is my collectionView's cellForItemAtIndexPath function. I have a timer in it to call another function to renew the logged account's data.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //updateUI methods..

    if (// a rare situation ){
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0
                           target:self
                           selector:@selector(refreshSingleVMStatusForTimer:)
                           userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
         });
     }
}
```

and here is refreshSingleVMStatusForTimer function to download all the data from internet then call `[collectionView reloadData]` to update it.

```
- (void) refreshSingleVMStatusForTimer :(NSTimer *) timer {

    //download the data from internet
    //parse the xml to useful data.

    [collectionView reloadData];
}
```

So these two functions becomes a recursion.

Now If I switch account, my collectionView will load a different account's data in it. But the recursion is still running which will occur error.

I don't know whether I explain my problem clear or not. If you have any question, please tell me.

Comment: Your design is horribly wrong.  For one thing, `cellForItemAtIndexPath:` is called once per cell, so you are creating multiple timers to trigger the same action.  You need to create a refresh mechanism that is not driven by view changes.

Comment: Sorry I didn't put all my code on the question. The timer will be fired only in a rare situation. Not all the time there is a recursion running in my app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by Avi it is a design problem, that doesn't let you stop the recursion: You should not trigger a reload in `-cellForItem:atIndexPath:`. This is making the bock for gardeners. Remove it.

If there is a reason to do it there, isolate that and ask a new Q.

Comment: I admit, it's my design problem. I think as long as I remove the timer to none-UI-related-function, it will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make sure that "rare condition" eventually evaluates to false. If that value doesn't change, that recursive loop will never break.